# python-gitlab - how to modify project settings?

Tags: python, gitlab, python-gitlab

I'm writing a python module to create projects in gitlab, but I can't figure out how to change the default project settings, like `remove_source_branch_after_merge`.

I've tried passing the argument to the `projects.create()` call, but it seems to be ignored.

```
project = gl.projects.create({'name': reponame, 'namespace_id': group_id, 'default_branch' : default_branch, 'remove_source_branch_after_merge' : False})
```

I managed to change the setting by manually POST'ing to `/api/v4/projects/$ID?remove_source_branch_after_merge=false` but I can't figure out how to do this in python-gitlab.

How can I create a project with customized settings, or modify a project settings after its creation in `python-gitlab`?

I'm using `python-gitlab==1.7.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question, modifying attributes after an object has been created can be done with `save()`:

```py
import gitlab

gl = gitlab.Gitlab("https://gitlab.example.com", private_token=token)
project = gl.projects.create(
    {
        "name": reponame,
        "namespace_id": group_id,
        "default_branch": default_branch,
        "remove_source_branch_after_merge": False,
    }
)

# Enable remove after merge
project.remove_source_branch_after_merge = True
project.save()

# Or disable again
project.remove_source_branch_after_merge = False
project.save()
```

However, I think your initial create call *should* work, so maybe check for any typos. 1.7.0 is quite old, and I just checked this works on 3.2.0. You can also use `gl.enable_debug()` to get verbose output and check that the right parameters are sent to the API.

Comment: Thank you, the `project.save()` trick did it!